# I want to use broadcast and services on the same activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

My service starts browser and when i stop this service my UI has a textview which updates some message to show that broadcast was reeceived but i am not able to do so !

My MainActivity.java file :-

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}


public void startService(View view){
    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyService.class));
}

public void stopService(View view){
    stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyService.class));
}
}
```

My Broadcast receiving file is MyReceiver.java

```
 public class MyReceiver extends Activity {

private TextView txtvw;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){ 
        @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
            }
        };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("BROWSER_STOPPED");
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    txtvw = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
    txtvw.setText("Done");

}

protected void onResume(){

    super.onResume();
}

}
```

This is my Service file MyService.java

```
    public class MyService extends Service{

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg1){
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    showBrowser();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super .onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // For sending Broadcast
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyReceiver.class);
            intent.setAction("BROWSER_STOPPED");
            sendBroadcast(intent);

}

protected void showBrowser(){

    String url = "http://www.google.com";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    this.startActivity(i);
}
}
```

My Layout file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:onClick="startService"
    android:text="Start Browser" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:onClick="stopService"
    android:text="Stop Browser" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="93dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

My manifest file :

```
 <application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<service android:name=".MyService"/>

<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="BROWSER_STOPPED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find one issue in manifest. You cannot declare activity as a broadcast receiver.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".MyService"/>

    <!--<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" >-->
        <!--<intent-filter>-->
            <!--<action android:name="BROWSER_STOPPED" />-->
        <!--</intent-filter>-->
    <!--</receiver>-->
</application>
```

**Edit:**
MyReceiver is not required I think as it has the same layout as the main activity. Instead you can use MainActivity as the broadcast receiver.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private TextView txtvw;
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    private IntentFilter filter;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume");
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("BROWSER_STOPPED");

        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onReceive");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                txtvw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                txtvw.setText("Done");

            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(TAG, "unregistered");
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    public void startService(View view) {
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }

    public void stopService(View view){
        stopService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
    }
}
```

Note that the receiver is registered in onPause() and unregistered in onResume(). You want it to be active only if the Activity is in the foreground. Now, if you register the receiver in onCreate() and unregister in onDestroy(), when the browser is shown by your service, the receiver will be unregistered in onDestroy() method. Now, when you stop the service, the receiver is no longer listening for the broad cast.

Also, some change is required in the Service class.

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // For sending Broadcast
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("BROWSER_STOPPED");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

The intent is not targeted at MyReceiver class.

Comment: But commenting the same isn't gonna help.. It works fine if i make that class MyReceiver as an Broadcast receiver instead of an activity but i want the receiver to be an activity